Azure AI Search - singular vs plural search terms
I have a search index in Azure AI Search using the newest version of the API (2024-07-01).
I have added searchable text fields with analyzer and synonymMaps. I am using the "en.microsoft" lexical analyzer.
I have some problems with language handling of the query search term.
More specifically, I have problems with handing of singular vs plural.
When I search with the term "squat" I get results containing "squat" or "squats".
This is expected.
But when I search with the term "squats" (plural form) I only get results containing "squats".
I was expecting the system to also return results containing "squat".
This example was in English, but I also have a Norwegian search index and I face the same singular/plural problem there, using the "nb.microsoft" lexical analyzer.
What do I have to do to solve this?

Clarification,
The lexical analyzer works fine in the indexed documents, I think.
I appears like it is the search term that does not get any lexical handling.
That is my own theory about the problem.

Could you please add to your question: the JSON definition of a field and the full JSON query that you are sending for both "squat" and "squats"?
